# Sum Involving Hermite Polynomials and Their Generating Function

Tags: physics, generating-functions, quantum-mechanics, hermite-polynomials

I'm reading the 3rd edition of Sakurai and Napolitano's *Modern Quantum Mechanics*, and have hit a bit of a snag with a sum involving the Hermite polynomials.

The authors define the Hermite polynomials through the generating function

\begin{equation*}
g(x,t) = e^{-t^{2}+2xt} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{H_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}}
\end{equation*}

and derive the familiar relation that

\begin{equation}
H_{n}'(x) = 2nH_{n-1}(x)
\end{equation}

(where prime represents differentiation with respect to the argument $x$). Then, (on p. 100), they write

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial g}{\partial t} &= -2tg(x,t) + 2xg(x,t)\\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2H_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2xH_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}}\\
&= -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2nH_{n-1}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2xH_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}}.
\end{align}

Somehow, I'm having trouble seeing how the authors arrive at the ultimate equality. It seems like $H'_{n}(x) = 2nH_{n-1}(x)$ is used, but the derivative with respect to $x$ doesn't show up in the series and I don't see how it could be incorporated by considering the formula as a series expansion of some function.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, and would appreciate any advice-I've been hung up on this for a while.

Comment: The sum is just being reindexed slightly, write $m = n+1$ and rewrite everything in terms of $m$, then rename $m$ back to $n$.

Comment: That makes sense! So then one gets

\begin{equation*}
-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2H_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}} = -\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{2mH_{m-1}(x)\frac{t^{m}}{m!}}.
\end{equation*}

But the authors include the $m = 0$ case in the sum after that step, even though they haven't defined $H_{-1}(x)$. Maybe this is OK since the term is 

\begin{equation*}
2\cdot 0\cdot H_{-1}(x)\frac{t^{0}}{0!} = 0?
\end{equation*}

Comment: I assume that's the intended interpretation but it's a bit sloppy and it would've been better to start the sum from $1$, I think.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll use your interpretation.